# Using custom background color and/or image in more tab from tab bar

Tags: iphone, view, colors, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I use a custom image in the navbar (although a solid color would be okay). I've added the image to all my views using setBackgroundImage but now when the more view loads it's blue and looks awkwardly different from the rest of the views. How can I set the image or color of the more view and the corresponding configure view? Is there some sort of controller I should make? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean how to apply the same image to every navigation bar, then put the following in your app delegates `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageName"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**EDIT:** Place this in the viewDidLoad method of your first view controller:

```
[[[self.tabBarController moreNavigationController] navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: That still didn't change the more bar from the tab controller :(

Comment: @bkcw5 Sorry about that I didn't realize that was what you meant. Please see my edit.